# Найдите гипотенузу треугольника с заданными катетами

Tags: java

Дано два числа a и b. Найдите гипотенузу треугольника с заданными катетами.

Входные данные
В двух строках вводятся два числа (числа целые,положительные, не превышают 1000).

Выходные данные
Выведите ответ на задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы найти гипотенузу нужно знать ее формулу. По т. Пифагора это `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`.

### Реализация

Будет 3 переменные a,b,c. a - первый катет, b - второй катет, с - гипотенуза. После ввода пользователем a и b нужно будет посчитать формулу `c = a*a + b*b` и потом посчитать корень c для получения уже ответа `а`, не `с^2`, потом в файл записываем ответ